# Accidentally cancelled inceptionV3 during install, now can't install at all

Tags: python, tensorflow

i was setting up tensorflow for image classification, and after i ran :

```
 -m scripts.retrain 
--bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks 
--model_dir=tf_files/models/"${ARCHITECTURE}" 
--summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"${ARCHITECTURE}" 
--output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb 
--output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt 
--architecture="${ARCHITECTURE}" 
--image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos
```

It automatically started installing inception, i realized that i needed to change some options so i cancelled the install of inception.
Now i believe that i have a half install that doesn't let me install the full package or use the half package.

I may be wrong, but any suggestions would be appreciated.
FYI: i've run :
pip install inception, to which i receive a "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in {my local/temp dir}

I also just tried running the scripts.retrain again, to which i receive a "EOFError: compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached"

Running on Windows 7

Comment: try to delete all files/folders already downloaded (e.g. bottleneck_dir, model_dir, ...) and then run again

Comment: So, was `pip install inception` that gave you problems? Try reinstalling whatever you canceled adding the `--ignore-installed` flag